# Redox Reactions with buckyballs

Tags: organic-chemistry

I have read that buckyballs are excellent electron acceptors, C60 in particular can accept up to 6 electrons.

However I do not understand why they have this ability and how they can accept a large number of electrons. I would appreciate if anyone could elaborate on this topic.

Comment: It's only 1e for 10 C atoms nothing special

Comment: you should look into chemistry of aromatic hydrocarbon anion-radicals and molecular orbital theory.

Comment: Triply degenerate [LUMO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HOMO/LUMO), that's why.